# Add a new function to Elgg River

Tags: php, content-management-system, elgg

I'm trying to add functionality in a new tab I added on my custom mod/myplugin/views/default/page/layouts/content.php and remove some elements based on their tags from the main activity.

```
    $tabs = array(
    'all' => array(
        'text' => elgg_echo('all'),
        'href' => (isset($vars['all_link'])) ? $vars['all_link'] : "$context/all",
        'selected' => ($filter_context == 'all'),
        'priority' => 200,
    ),
    'mine' => array(
        'text' => elgg_echo('mine'),
        'href' => (isset($vars['mine_link'])) ? $vars['mine_link'] : "$context/owner/$username",
        'selected' => ($filter_context == 'mine'),
        'priority' => 300,
    ),
    'anime' => array(
        'text' => elgg_echo('Anime'),
        'href' => (isset($vars['anime_link'])) ? $vars['anime_link'] : "$context/anime",
        'selected' => ($filter_context == 'anime'),
        'priority' => 500,
    ),
        );
```

The tab already appears into my activity page, however I don't know where I can add my new function to load only certain items that has the "anime" tag.

So my questions are:

**Where can I add the code for this:** example.com/activity/anime

**Where can I edit the query of this (so it shows everything but items with the "anime" tag):** example.com/activity/all

**Do I need to add a filter to achieve this? Where should I add it or what file should I override if that's the case?**

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can go about it:

1. Use a custom page handler and use as the URL for your new tab, e.g. `anime/activity`.

   ```
   elgg_register_page_handler('anime', 'anime_page_handler');

   function anime_page_handler($segments) {

       $page = array_shift($segments);

       switch ($page) {
           case 'activity':

               // render a page using elgg_view_resource()
               // or generate your list here and pass it into elgg_view_layout() then
               // then pass the layout into elgg_view_page()
               return true;
       }

       return false;
   }
   ```
2. Use the `route` hook to hijack the route for `activity/anime`

   ```
   elgg_register_plugin_hook_handler('route', 'activity', 'anime_router');

   function anime_router($hook, $type, $return, $params) {

       $identifier = elgg_extract('identifier', $return);
       $segments = elgg_extract('segments', $return);

       if ($identifier == 'activity' && $segments[0] == 'anime') {
           // render your page

           return false; // terminate further routing by returning false
       }
   }
   ```